# Excel VBA help - Multiple key value records output from a single concatenated string of keys mapped to one value

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I have 2 columns of data. One is the Value and the other is a semicolon-delimited list of key strings. I need to break open this second column and associate the values with individual keys as individual key-value pairs.

INPUT : `Value1 "key1;key2"`

OUTPUT

```
Value1 Key1 
Value1 Key2
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? This is fairly simple string manipulation :)  And *where* do you want this output? Please consider revising your question to more thoroughly describe what you have tried so far, and what the desired result will be.

Comment: I'm looking for excel vba help. that's really it.

Comment: yes I understand you're looking for Excel VBA help. What part of your code is giving you trouble? And on that note, please post your code.

Comment: You can use the split function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below sample code

```
Sub sample()
    Dim strValue As String

      s = 2
    For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        strValue = Range("B" & i).Value
        retval = Split(strValue, ";")

        For j = LBound(retval) To UBound(retval)

            Range("C" & s) = Range("A" & i).Value
            Range("D" & s) = retval(j)
            s = s + 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This puts the updated/split list on a new worksheet.

```
Sub SplitKeyVals()    
Dim wsMe As Worksheet: Set wsMe = ActiveSheet
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Dim rngKeys As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim keyVals() As String
Dim k As Variant
Dim r As Long: r = 1
Dim myDelimiter as String

Set wsNew = Worksheets.Add(Before:=ActiveSheet) '## Modify as needed ##'
Set rngKeys = wsMe.Range("A2:A10") '## Modify as needed ##'

'## We will use this delimiter value later ##'
myDelimiter = ";"

'## Iterate over each cell in rngKeys.Cells ##'
For Each cl In rngKeys.Cells
    '## Use the Split function to split a delimited string in to
    ' an array, so we can iterate over the values. '
    keyVals = Split(cl.Offset(0, 1).Value, myDelimiter)

    '## Now that the values are in array, iterate over the
    ' array items: '
    For Each k In keyVals
        '## Do something with this information ##'
        wsNew.Cells(r, 1) = cl.Value
        wsNew.Cells(r, 2) = k
        '## Increase the destination row for output ##'
        r = r + 1
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. I needed some help with the use of Excel constructs such as Sheets and Ranges. This helps. Thx.